# Flame Emblem and Cape

Tags: minifigures, design

I'd like to build a minifig with [this flame emblem on the chest](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=98138pb022&C=98#T=C&C=98).
Typically, this is done with an armor piece such as [this](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11098&idColor=115#T=C&C=115). However, I also want to give the figure a cape, and I'm not sure if that will fit with the armor.  Is there an alternative way to put a 1x1 round tile on the chest of a minifigure? Has anyone had experience doing something like this?

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered putting that tile on a [Minifigure, Neck Bracket with Back Stud - Thin Back Wall](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=42446&name=Minifigure,%20Neck%20Bracket%20with%20Back%20Stud%20-%20Thin%20Back%20Wall&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Body%20Wear%5D#T=P)?  Normally this is used to put something on a minifig's back, but it could also work on the chest.

Answer (score 2):

Some minifigures have a [combination with a cape](https://www.bricklink.com/ML/loc043.jpg) you are looking for.

Comment: ..and they would clearly show that you can fit both accessories. See, this is why you should Google your question before you even bother to ask an excessively easy-to-answer question.